# OLAP Cube process error (A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Example_SQL', Name of 'ExampleSQL'.)

Tags: .net, .net-core, olap, cube

I have an Analysis Services Multidimensional Project, I added a data source, data source view, and cube, from dimensions > properties > explore data > I got all data from DB.
From cube processing I'm getting the following errors (see attachment):[cube procces view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjnSa.png)

I added "NT SERVICE\MSSQLServerOLAPService" this a login in SQL> Security> logins, set "sysadmin" role

Comment: username and password are not correct, not sure what more do you expect us to tell you?